# Multiple IPs shown when only one exists possibly causing random/temporary Internet loss

Tags: networking

I don't believe I made any changes recently, so thinking maybe an apt update somewhere plays a role. When logging in, my WAN IP **WAS** the only one displayed as expected. Recently, we've had random WAN loses, and it now shows 3 IPS. The 1 displayed in the welcome message is an old one that no longer exists. In enp4s0f0, the FIRST inet is current/accurate, but the SECOND inet I do not recognize and was not an item listed in the past. It's also displaying 2 IPv6 addresses now, but I've only had 1 set.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-37-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon May 23 01:16:22 PM UTC 2022

  System load:               0.28955078125
  Usage of /:                4.5% of 915.81GB
  Memory usage:              27%
  Swap usage:                0%
  Processes:                 179
  Users logged in:           0
  IPv4 address for enp4s0f0: 75.128.204.107
  IPv6 address for enp4s0f0: 2600:6c44:7025:200:8d37:f89a:4b4f:557a
  IPv4 address for enp4s0f1: 192.168.0.1

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings


Last login: Sun Jun 12 08:00:00 2022 from 192.168.0.51
triple_nothing@hzi:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 2: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:48:64:b7:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 47.34.32.179/23 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global dynamic enp4s0f0
       valid_lft 56926sec preferred_lft 56926sec
    inet 68.114.243.105/21 metric 100 brd 68.114.247.255 scope global dynamic enp4s0f0
       valid_lft 27616sec preferred_lft 27616sec
    inet6 2600:6c44:7025:200:8d37:f89a:4b4f:557a/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 315086sec preferred_lft 315086sec
    inet6 fe80::230:48ff:fe64:b74e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 3: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:48:64:b7:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp4s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::230:48ff:fe64:b74f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
triple_nothing@hzi:~$
```

And this is my basic setup of netplan. I have 2 physical ports. enp4s0f0 to my Internet modem and enp4s0f1 to my switch/router's WAN.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp4s0f1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

I went ahead and ran sudo dhclient -r enp4s0f0 and sudo dhclient enp4s0f0 to release/renew. This DOES remove a v4 inet, but NOT a v6, but a second DOES reappear after reboot.

```
triple_nothing@hzi:/etc/netplan$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:48:64:b7:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 47.34.36.224/23 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global dynamic enp4s0f0
       valid_lft 3591sec preferred_lft 3591sec
    inet6 2600:6c44:7025:200:8d37:f89a:4b4f:557a/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 313463sec preferred_lft 313463sec
    inet6 fe80::230:48ff:fe64:b74e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:48:64:b7:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp4s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::230:48ff:fe64:b74f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
triple_nothing@hzi:/etc/netplan$
```

After such update, when logging out and back in, the welcome message will still display a past IP.